# Which Array method should I overwrite?

Tags: ruby

I would like to extend an Ruby Array object, to make it returns Array.new if it's nil.

**My solution:**

Overwrite `[]` and `at`.

```
module NullSafeArray
  def at(index)
    value = super
    return Array.new if value.nil?
    value
  end

  def [](index)
    value = super
    return Array.new if value.nil?
    value
  end
end
```

**The problem:**

This works:

```
assert_equal Array.new [].to_be_null_safe[3]
```

But this will fail:

```
a, b = [nil, 2].to_be_null_safe
assert_equal Array.new, a
```

Which method else should be overwritten to do this?

**Update:**

Your answer should passes this:

```
a, b = [9].to_null_safe
assert a == 9
assert b == Array.new
```

It could be `a, b, c, d =`. You don't know how many comma there is.

I guess you know what method to overwrite by looking about Ruby's source code, I tried, but it's kind of hard to find it.

Comment: What does the `to_be_null_safe` method do? Does it return an instance of a subclass of `Array`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend Array class like this below

```
class Array
  def to_null_safe!
    each_with_index  do |variable, index|
      self[index] = "HELLO" if variable.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you should name your method `to_null_safe!`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def to_be_null_safe
    map { |value| value.nil? ? "HELLO" : value }
  end
end
```

Also consider to use a custom object if you need to override lot of methods, instead of cluttering the `Array` space.

Comment: This will also convert `false` values.